# "message": "Key path \"file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key\" does not exist or is not readable" in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-passport

Getting error in Heroku server when try to login with Laravel passport Api. Migration and key generation every working fine. But working fine locally.

Can anyone help me how to generate this key in heroku server by using :

```
heroku run php artisan passport:key
```

Thank you for your valuable time.
Full error message

```
{
"message": "Key path \"file:///app/storage/oauth-private.key\" does not exist or is not readable",
"exception": "LogicException",
"file": "/app/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php",
"line": 48,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PassportServiceProvider.php",
        "line": 243,
        "function": "__construct",
        "class": "League\\OAuth2\\Server\\CryptKey",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/app/vendor/laravel/passport/src/PassportServiceProvider.php",
        "line": 209,
        "function": "makeCryptKey",
        "class": "Laravel\\Passport\\PassportServiceProvider",
        "type": "->"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Can you include the full error message in the body of the post?

Comment: added response from server in Postman.

Comment: login to the heroku terminal, and check is the file exists or not

Answer (score 2):

**You do not mention your installation steps. Presume you did the following:**

```
composer require laravel/passport
```

**Register the service provider inside config/app.php**

```
Laravel\Passport\PassportServiceProvider::class,
```

**Run the migrations**

```
php artisan migrate
```

**Lastly generate the keys using**

```
php artisan passport:install
```

Comment: I did these all the things

Comment: not working. This is the initial step, I have done it but error is same

Comment: please mark as verified this  answer if its help for you thank you @Ajoy

Answer (score 1):

Laravel PassPort uses oauth2 which uses an asymmetric encryption algorithm. So you have to generate the public and private keys.
You just have to type this command in your Laravel project to generate these keys. They will be in the storage folder.

```
php artisan passport:keys
```

For more information, see the laravel document.
Laravel Doc : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#password-grant-tokens

Another solution is to go to the .gitignore file and delete the ***

> storage / *. Keys

*** line
before pushing to github

Comment: Please include some explanation with your answer - one-liners are useful, but it doesn't help the person asking the question as much as a full answer should.